# Efficiently splitting an array of integers into subarrays of their prime divisors so that no two sub arrays contain overlapping prime divisors

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, primes

I am currently trying to split an integer array into sub arrays so that:

- No two different sub arrays contain elements that have any common prime divisors.
- Elements that share prime divisors are placed into the same sub array.

e.g. an array contatining 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 14, 19 would be split into two arrays [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 14] and [19].

I've figured out a working solution, but i think it's crude and inefficient and I was wondering if there was a way to optimize it.

The solution:

```
public class SOExample {

    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> integersPrimesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<Set<Integer>> primesSubArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Set<Integer> usedIntegers = new HashSet<>();

    public SOExample(int[] arr) {
        for (int i : arr) {
            calculatePrimeFactors(i);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> x : integersPrimesMap.entrySet()) {
            primesSubArrays.add(x.getValue());
        }
        // Combine sub arrays which contain overlapping elements
        Iterator<Set<Integer>> i = primesSubArrays.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Set<Integer> x = i.next();
            for (Set<Integer> j : primesSubArrays) {
                if (x != j && !Collections.disjoint(x, j)) {
                    j.addAll(x);
                    i.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // figure out which integer belongs to which sub array from their prime divisors in integersPrimesMap and create sub arrays of integers.
    }

    private void calculatePrimeFactors(int n) {
        if (usedIntegers.contains(n)) {
            return;
        }
        usedIntegers.add(n);
        Set<Integer> factors = new HashSet<>();
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            factors.add(2);
            n = n / 2;
        }
        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                n = n / i;
            }
            while (n % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                n = n / i;
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (n > 2) {
            factors.add(n);
        }
        integersPrimesMap.put(n, factors);
    }
}
```

My biggest struggle is with combining sub arrays of the integers prime factors, my current solution is O(n^2). I'm fairly certrain that it can be done faster but I was unable to work out the answer by my self.

Comment: the part that takes the most amount of time is the function calculatePrimeFactors its complexity is O(sqrt(n)) where n is the element, usually the elements are much bigger than the size of the array because it wont be interesting to input the function the array [0,1,...,n] or an array with a repeating number

Comment: Your example is wrong. 2 and 3 can't be in the same list, they don't share prime divisors. My sublists are 2: [2, 6, 14]
3: [3, 9]
7: [7]
19: [19]

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk there is no such rule. also 6 and 3 has common prime factor. the idea is to maximize the amount of lists while every list have different prime factors

Comment: @Ofek: Thank you for clarifying. I thought rule #2 required all the elements to share a prime divisor

Comment: I still don't get it. Condition 1 seems to be at odds with Condition 2. A DAG would probably be more suited then a list?

Comment: @Neil Both conditions are the same. they are saying that a two numbers are: at the same array OR don't have prime factor. technically the input satisfy this condition, so the idea is to maximize the amount of arrays.

Comment: (1) Your two conditions allow the possibility of just returning the original array. You also need a third condition, or else to specify that you want to split it into as many subarrays as possible. (2) The term "subarray" often means specifically "contiguous subarray", and your example is consistent with either interpretation. Can you clarify? (3) Your current solution doesn't work, because at no point does it merge two sets of primes that don't overlap but later turn out to both overlap some third set (for example, `[2,3], [5,7], [2,5]` should become `[2, 3, 5, 7]` but doesn't).

Comment: Oh, you start out with numbers and then group them by each prime factors? In the case where `[1, n]`, I wounder if it's bounded? If it was a DAG, how many disconnected components.

Comment: @ruakh about 3, you have the same mistake everyone is doing. the conditions are saying that every two numbers that sharing prime factor are in the same array, NOT every two numbers in the same array are sharing prime factor.

Comment: @Ofek: I have *not* made that mistake. You must have misread my comment.

Answer (score 1):

this algorithm is with complexity of O(n^2*log(m)) when n is the length of the array and m is the maximum element in the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int[] result : split(new int[] {2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 14, 19})) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}

//Complexity: O(n^2 * m)    [ n=arr.length, m=max(arr) ]
public static int[][] split(int[] arr) {
    List<LinkedList> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n : arr) {
        LinkedList selectedList = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            LinkedList list = lists.get(i);
            if (list.hasNumberWithCommonPrimeFactor(n)) {
                if (selectedList == null) {//if we haven't added the number yet
                    //add the number to the set
                    selectedList = list;
                    list.add(n);
                } else {
                    //join the lists
                    selectedList.joinAfter(list);
                    lists.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        if (selectedList == null) {//if we haven't added the number
            //let put the number inside a new list
            lists.add(new LinkedList(n));
        }
    }
    //convert the sets to arrays
    return lists.stream().map(LinkedList::toArray).toArray(int[][]::new);
}

//gcd function with complexity O(log(a+b))
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return a % b == 0 ? b : gcd(b, a % b);
}

private static class LinkedList {
    public Node first;
    public Node last;
    public int size;

    //Complexity: O(1)
    public LinkedList(int firstValue) {
        first = last = new Node(firstValue);
        size = 1;
    }

    //Complexity: O(1)
    public void add(int value) {
        last = last.next = new Node(value);
        size++;
    }

    //Complexity: O(1)
    public void joinAfter(LinkedList other) {
        last.next = other.first;
        last = other.last;
        size += other.size;
    }

    //Complexity: O(n)
    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        Node node = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = node.value;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    //Complexity: O(n)
    public boolean hasNumberWithCommonPrimeFactor(int num) {
        Node node = first;
        while (node != null) {
            if (gcd(node.value, num) > 1)
                return true;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private static class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

this will print

```
[2, 6, 3, 9, 14, 7]
[19]
```

the idea I was using is that gcd(a,b)==1 if and only if a,b aren't sharing any prime factor

Answer (score 1):

This can run better than quadratic if `sqrt(max(list))` is significantly less than the input length, although we could possibly improve that with a precalculated list of primes to reduce factoring time. It's `O(n) * sqrt(max(list)) + O(num unique primes in list)`, assuming the disjoint-set data structure is [practically amortised constant time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Time_complexity).

Python code (sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Java):

```py
# The Disjoint set (by Matt Timmermans)
# has the value as either the size of the set
# in case of the parent, or the negative index
# of the parent in case of a child.
def find(ds, idx):
  if ds[idx] > 0:
    return idx

  root = find(ds, -ds[idx])

  # Path compression
  if ds[idx] != -root:
    ds[idx] = -root

  return root

# Returns False if the
# elements are ALREADY
# in the same set.
def union(ds, a, b):
  a_root = find(ds, a)
  b_root = find(ds, b)

  if a_root == b_root:
    return False

  # Union by size
  if ds[a_root] >= ds[b_root]:
    ds[a_root] += ds[b_root]
    ds[b_root] = -a_root
  else:
    ds[b_root] += ds[a_root]
    ds[a_root] = -b_root

  return True

# End code by by Matt Timmermans


def prime_factors(n):
  primes = []
  
  i = 2
  
  while i*i <= n:
    if n % i == 0:
      primes.append(i)
      while n % i == 0:
        n //= i
    i += 1

  if n > 1:
    primes.append(n)

  return primes


import collections


def update(ds, m, val, index):
  if val in m:
    return index
  m[val] = index
  if len(ds) < index + 1:
    ds.append(1)
  return index + 1


def f(A):
  ds = []
  prime_index = 0
  prime_to_index = {}
  factor_list = [0] * len(A)

  for i, a in enumerate(A):
    ps = prime_factors(a)

    factor_list[i] = ps[0]
    prime_index = update(ds, prime_to_index, ps[0], prime_index)

    ps_0_idx = prime_to_index[ps[0]]

    for j in range(1, len(ps)):
      prime_index = update(ds, prime_to_index, ps[j], prime_index)
      idx = prime_to_index[ps[j]]
      union(ds, ps_0_idx, idx)

  result = collections.defaultdict(list)

  for i, factor in enumerate(factor_list):
    parent = find(ds, prime_to_index[factor])
    result[parent].append(A[i])

  return list(result.values())
```

Output:

```
A = [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 14, 19]

print(f(A)) # [[2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 14], [19]]
```

Comment: its most likely that there are no repeats in the array, so the array is at least [1,2,3,4,...,n] and the lowest number is n not sqrt(n)

Comment: @Ofek I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you help me understand?

Comment: i miss read, i thought you said that `sqrt(list.length)` need to be smaller than `max(list)`. i have said that `max(list)` is bigger than `list.length`